# how can i count the number of digits in a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know isdigit returns true or false if the complete string is a number but I wanna check if the string contains a number like for example  "1dfsfsfs" would return false but it does contain a digit. So which method would I use to find this out ?

```
.isdigit()
```

Comment: Check each character in the string in turn. See also e.g. the `any()` function, which makes tasks like that easier.

Comment: isdigit() will always return false if your string has more than just digits. Why not use the str.count function?

Comment: If you just need to return a boolean you can use regex to match any digit in the string `\d`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this with map and lambda

```
a= "a12345"
sum(list(map(lambda x:1 if x.isdigit() else 0,set(a))))
```

it will give you count of digit in string

explanation:
set(a) --convert string into unique item (because map function take an iterator or list for mapping it to a function )

```
lambda x:1 if x.isdigit() else 0
```

this lambda function help us to find if it digit then it will return 1 and if not it will return 0

```
list(map(lambda x:1 if x.isdigit() else 0,set(a)))
```

this will return somthing like this [0,1,1,1,1,1]

```
sum([0,1,1,1,1,1])
```

this will sum all the value in list and in this way you find the count

Comment: your code works for exactly what I'm trying to do can you explain it a bit more in-depth so i can understand?

Comment: ok I added in answer hope it will help you

Comment: I notice that this code counts repeated numbers is there a way to make it so that it doesn't recount digits already acknowledged

Comment: @AngelValenzuela Instead of `list(a)` in the `map` function, you can put `list(set(a))`

Comment: use set(a)  no need to convert it again list set will contain only unique values  check answer i updated it